Group theory, selection rules and anti-unitary symmetries
In quantum mechanics we often need to evaluate matrix elements of the type $\langle \psi|H|\phi\rangle$, and regular group theory for linear symmetry operators give us selection rules saying that the matrix element is zero if the product of the representations for $\psi$, $H$ and $\phi$ do not contain the trivial or identity representation $\Gamma_1$ of the relevant group. Namely, we write the selection rules as
$$\Gamma^*_\psi \otimes \Gamma_H \otimes \Gamma_\phi = \sum_i a_i \Gamma_i$$
If the resulting sum on the right does not contain $\Gamma_1$, the matrix element is zero.
Now, there are the magnetic groups and antiunitary symmetries originally discussed by Wigner, which occur due to time-reversal symmetry. I've been studing these cases and the related concept of corepresentations, but I couldn't find discussions about selection rules for magnetic groups. Am I missing something?
Alternativelly, for a unitary symmetry $U$, we can analyze the matrix element using that $U^\dagger U = 1$, and
$$\langle \psi|H|\phi\rangle = \langle U\psi|UHU^\dagger|U\phi\rangle$$
Then, one can verify how each element transform due to $U$ to verify if the equation above result in possible absurds like $\langle \psi|H|\phi\rangle = - \langle \psi|H|\phi\rangle$, which implies that the matrix element must be zero.
But this does not work for antiunitary symmetries $A = UK$, where $U$ is unitary and $K$ is complex conjugation, due to the fact that wavefunctions have arbitrary global phase.
Am I missing something or is it not possible to define extra selection rules from these antiunitary symmetries?
There are some discussions on the literature, but they only consider particular cases and never the general matrix element as in usual representation theory. Check for instance:
N. B. Backhouse, Extra selection rules, J. Math. Phys. 15, 119–124 (1974)
